# Access basler camera through IP address

Tags: basler

How can get live stream from basler camera through IP address?

I am following the basler documentation

https://docs.baslerweb.com/overview-of-the-pylon-ip-configurator

Answer (score 0):

if by live stream you mean RTSP compressed stream or similar, then Basler pylon does not give you such direct possibility.

Pylon SDK is meant to be used for Basler's industrial grade cameras that operate with uncompressed image buffers via pylon API (C++, .NET, ect). So pylon gives you access to camera and image data as such and does not do much more.

To address RSTP streaming, with pylon you can generally create a custom worker application that connects and runs camera on the one hand, creates and maintains RTSP stream with use of i.e. FFmpeg/FF on the other, and feeds this stream with incoming image buffers.

Some related links:
https://docs.baslerweb.com/pylonapi/
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide/

---

Or, if you just want to initialize camera & have live image preview on screen - use pylon Viewer, it has fullscreen function.

IP Configurator is the tool for matching device IP with your NIC card for GigE based Basler cameras. Tutorial how to set up GigE cameras and make them visible in Pylon Viewer:
https://docs.baslerweb.com/assigning-an-ip-address-to-a-camera